# Read ASCII file (ask for file name as input), checks if it has more than two words and prints out the two first words of the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii

I am new to Python and the above is a homework practice problem I am trying to work on. After doing some research and playing around with a few things I have come across the module ASCIItable which allows me to read data files (not just int - originally I was trying numpy but ran into issues since my file contains both str/int)

The firs question I had was, where does ASCII look for the files? Where should my text file be located.

I started with the first part of the problem which is

```
name = str(raw_input("Please enter the name of the file: "))
```

Looking for some help on where to go from here. (link i've been using for reference http://cxc.harvard.edu/contrib/asciitable/)

Edit: I am going to assume that the file although not mentioned is only Str deliminated via spaces

Thanks in advance

Comment: No need for `str(raw_input())`. `raw_input()` returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Python script will look for files (unless you provide an absolute path, of course) in the current directory. This usually is the same directory that your script is in, but that depends on how you call it.

Comment: Then it's the directory your Python installation is in. Of course, you can provide a relative path, too (say, if you enter `./dir/myfile.txt`, then the script will look in the subdirectory `dir` for the file `myfile.txt`. Enter `import os` and then `os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` to find out where you are.